# Facebook connection with stackoverflow

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, facebook

Can we have Facebook Like link in Stackoverflow??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can, but you can add it yourself:

- Bookmarklet: [How to "Like" Anything on the Web (Safely)](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/how_to_like_anything_on_the_web_safely.php)
- Firefox add-on: [Facebook Like](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/162124/)

You can share anything you like on every site, you don't really need a monster "share this" button.